# SQL: getting hours between 2 dates on the same day with Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

i have a table EMPLOYETIMES where the time is logged and a key is set from arriving (key is 100) and departing (key is 101).

I added calculated fields, one with ARRIVAL and one with DEPARTURE, in those fields i have the following expressions:

ARRIVAL

```
= IIF (Fields!KEY_MODE.Value=100,Fields!EMPLOYETIMES.Value, nothing)
```

and

DEPARTURE

```
= IIF (Fields!KEY_MODE.Value=101,Fields!EMPLOYETIMES.Value, nothing)
```

I also tried using SWITCH like this:

ARRIVAL

```
= SWITCH (Fields!KEY_MODE.Value=100,Fields!EMPLOYETIMES.Value)
```

DEPARTURE

```
 = SWITCH (Fields!KEY_MODE.Value=101,Fields!EMPLOYETIMES.Value)
```

The results i get from those fields are like this:

18.01.2021 07:14

18.01.2021 17:23

and so on.

Then i added an expression to the tablix where i want to get the hours between ARRIVAL & DEPARTURE like this:

```
= DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!ARRIVAL.Value,Fields!DEPARTUE.Value)
```

But the results are not what i was expecting, i get numbers like:

-17707375

17707385

and so on.

What could i do to have those calculated the right way?

Answer (score 1):

This expression

`= DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!ARRIVAL.Value,Fields!DEPARTUE.Value)`

is calculated for each row, and no row has both ARRIVAL and DEPARTURE populated.  You'll need to aggregate them together.  Perhaps using MAX(), having your SQL query calculate them.

Comment: i'm still struggling with this, but i may have forgotten to tell that the DEPARTURE.Value is a calculated field i created, and report builder say aggregation on calculated fields is not allowed. If i use MAX() on EMPLOYETIMES in the query builder it still does the same thing and fills the fields with 17707385 / -17707385. Seems i just don't understand how this all works.